# Proving nondifferentiability at all points of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, continuity

**Given:**

$f_1(x)=x$ if $x\le1/2$

$f_1(x)=1-x$ if $1/2\le x\le1$

$f_1(x+1)=f_1(x)$

$\forall n\ge2,f_n(x)=(1/2)*f_{n-1}(2x)$

Let $S_m(x)=\sum_{n=1}^m f_n(x)$

$S_m$ is a continuous function on $[0,\infty]$

$(S_m)_{m\in N}$ converges uniformly to a continuous function $S$

**Task:**

Show that $S$ is not differentiable at any point in $(0,\infty)$

**My work/question:**

After drawing out $f_1$, $f_2$, and $f_3$, it seems to me that at every $k/(2^n)$, where $k,n$ are natural numbers, f is not differentiable. I don't know if this is useful. Does this expression account for all rational numbers?

It seems like a common thing to do with proving that a function is not differentiable is to consider the limit from the left and right. I don't really know where to go with this approach though.

**Per user117818's comment:**

$\lim_{h\to 0}(S_m(x+h)-S_m(x))/h=\lim_{h\to 0}(\sum_{n=1}^m [f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)])/h$
$= \sum_{n=1}^m (\lim_{h\to 0}(f_n(x+h)-f_n(x))/h)$

I guess this shows that, for every point $a$, if there exists an $n$ such that $f_n$ is not differentiable at $a$, then $S_m$ is not differentiable at this point either. Would it be possible to show that for every point $a$, there does indeed exist an $n$ that satisfies this condition?

Comment: note you can get arbitarily close to $x$ using $n(2^n-1)/2^n$

Comment: oldrinb: If my observation that $f'(k/(2^n))$ does not exist for all natural numbers $k,n$ is correct, then combined with your comment it would seem that arbitrarily close to any $x\in (0,\infty)$, lies a y where f is nondifferentiable. I'm not quite sure what to make of this.

Comment: Spivak has proof of this in his calculus book, using 10 instead of 2. The section is titled "series of functions and uniform convergence"

Comment: Is irrelevant that $f_n$ is not differentiable at some points. In the original example (Weierstrass) all the $f_n$ are sinusoids. The trick is making the graph a fractal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did some intense Googling and I found a proof for a very similar function that looks correct, albeit very very labor-intensive. If anyone is interested: http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~mdc/MATH20101/notesPermanant/Contsnondiff.pdf